AWS SES managed IP pool - Sender reputation when there's not enough volume for a specific ISP
I'm considering SES's managed IP pool feature to isolate sender reputation between different domains within the same account. I understand that I need to provide enough volume to build up sender reputation amongst each ISP, otherwise SES uses shared IP's.
Lets say that only a small fraction of the emails gets forwarded to ICloud and the rest to Gmail, Hotmail etc. Lets say this small fraction generates a lot of complaints. Which reputation metric is bumped? The one at account level (because it is a shared IP) or the configuration set level metrics wired to the managed IP pool?
